# Calling state changing functions from mapStateToProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am new to react-redux and I was surprised to see an example where a function, in this case being getVisiblieTodos, is called inside mapStateToProps. This function should be called in a reducer since it changes state? Is the code breaking "good form" for the sake of brevity? Is it okay to do this in general?

I am looking at code from this [link](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect#motivation-for-memoized-selectors)

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { toggleTodo } from '../actions'
import TodoList from '../components/TodoList'

const getVisibleTodos = (todos, filter) => {
  switch (filter) {
    case 'SHOW_ALL':
      return todos
    case 'SHOW_COMPLETED':
      return todos.filter(t => t.completed)
    case 'SHOW_ACTIVE':
      return todos.filter(t => !t.completed)
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    todos: getVisibleTodos(state.todos, state.visibilityFilter)
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onTodoClick: (id) => {
      dispatch(toggleTodo(id))
    }
  }
}

const VisibleTodoList = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(TodoList)

export default VisibleTodoList
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In redux we want the store to hold the minimal data needed for the app. Everything that is derived from the base data, should be computed on the fly, to prevent cloning pieces of the store, and the need to recompute all derived data when something changes in the store.

Since the visible todos list is not part of the store, but computed using the list of `todos`, and the `visibilityFilter`, the `getVisibleTodos()` doesn't change the store's state. It produces the derived computed data from the those two properties.

A function that is used to get data from the store, and compute derived data is known as a [*selector*](https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ComputingDerivedData.html). Using selectors, the derived data is not part of the store, and computed when needed. In addition, we can use memoized selectors, to save the computation overhead.

Comment: Do you by any chance know what the advantage of computing data in this manner, as opposed to the normal reducer usage?

Comment: @Andrew - it saves you the need to store multiple pieces of cloned data, that you have to recompute for every change.

Comment: This is a good answer, you are right, it's okay to hold the minimal data needed for the app. Also, my answer says some additional things like state complexity on the reducer. am I right on that?

Answer (score 1):

`todos` in this component is a calculated property based on the state of the reducer, and it is not changing any state.

It's okay to transform properties comming from recuders that are used only by one component (they are called `selectors`). Imagine that you use `todos` in other components, you will not want to make changes in one component like filtering and seeing that in the other components. If this is the case, it's fine to do it.

Also, it is a good property of your reducer to store only the needed data. More state is more complexity in the app, and more overhead to calculate new states.

Answer (score 1):

You may see `getVisibleTodos` as a reducer because it includes  "switch .. case" block or/and because it has 2 arguments . However, it is not a rule.

A redux reducer ( by definition) changes store state according to dispatched action , and that's why it takes two arguments ( store state + dispatched action ) and it returns new state for the store without mutation.

`getVisibleTodos` here is a helper function which filter an array according to string (filter).

Also , `filter` is not a redux-action, it is just string that decides todos to be rendered.

I may agree with you it is something weird , and if we can see the whole application (reducers, actions,... ) we can decide if it is best practices or not .

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that a function should do what its name says, nothing less, nothing more.

`mapStateToProps()` should just do that, ie "map", and should normally not call other functions.